# Stretching DIV totally across screen

Tags: css, width, html

So, here's my situation:

I have a div (see the code below), a pretty simple . When running the code, I come up with a gray box. BUT, my intention was for that gray box to span from the start of the browser window to the END of that browser window, while what the code below does is creating a gray box with what seems to be a white border.

```
<div style="height: 30px; background-color: gray; color: white;">
   Hey
</div>
```

I'm sorry for the lack of explanation, but I found no good way to word what I was trying to do. Thanks in advance,

Tom.

Comment: without seeing more code I think about `width:100%;` did you try that?

Comment: Possible duplicate (just realized) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, it still has a white border. I would recommend entering it into your localhost to see what's wrong.

Comment: Wow, so many duplicate answers...

Comment: reset margin on <body> to zero

Comment: Thanks, GCyrillus! That was it! Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep you height:

```
<div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: gray; color: white;">
   Hey
</div>
```

Also to get rid of white borders, add this: `body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }`

Comment: You don't need quotes around 100%

Answer (score 3):

If you want a div to fill all available space use the following:

```
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
```

You can define sizes in percentages of available space.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your correctly, you need width to be set to 100%

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: gray; color: white;">
   Hey
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `width:100%;` to say to the div to fill all the horizontal space.

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>  
<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="height: 30px; width: 100% background-color: gray; color: white;">
   Hey
</div>
</body>
```

I am assuming you want your div to be 30px high and the width all the way. To do that you just set the width of the div to `100%` and make sure the body has no padding(this can shift your elements to the the right a little. I recommend using reset.css)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should eliminate "px" after your sizes, I.E. `padding: 0;` as 0 needs no units.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `body` has margins and or padding by default on most browsers. You need to zero it out, as shown here. Many people use a CSS Reset (e.g. Meyer's CSS Reset) to zero out all the little oddities like this and make all browsers start from a common point.